# MVC how to trigger action on other server from html

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I want to make button that triggers an action on my local server from html page

this is my url

```
http://localhost:5720/convertor/changer/?strUrl=http://blabla.com/files/blabla.pdf
```

controller: convertor 
action: changer
the function gets url string: http://blabla.com/files/blabla.pdf

The controller works fine when I'm copying the url to the url bar, now I need to do exactly the same just with a button from the html page

note: I need to implant the button on different web page, it's not cshtml so using mvc html helpers won't work on this. it has to be from the client side (html,ajax)

Thanks in advance

Comment: I m not getting exact picture of what you really want but here's a flow :
1. parse your url to get the address to which you want to point your request.
2 .Perform and ajax request on button onclick event and hit the address you found out from step 1.

Here's a sample ajax :

$.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "http://blabla.com/files/blabla.pdf",
      
      success: function(result){
          alert("Sent successfully");
      }
});

Answer (score 2):

Simply use following code in another html page

```
<form action="http://localhost:5720/convertor/changer/strUrl=http://blabla.com/files/blabla.pdf" method="get">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```